# What species is this worm?

Tags: species-identification

I was at the park lying on the grass and its the third time I have seen them, I used to think they were parasites when I was like 7. It is the very small brown worm on the green leaf. It moves by squiggling. It comes in different colors but same size.

http://postimg.org/image/ea3x2nw95/
http://postimg.org/image/zfawh9pr1/

Comment: Location, time of year, and description of the habitat/vegitation are going to help.

Comment: Location: local park in Miami. Also found in trees as one spontaneously fell on my finger and squiggled on it mildly fast when I was 7, in Honduras. Time of year is both summertime/late spring. Lots of leaves

Comment: "Brown string" and "on the green leaf" are of little help for me at least: where is it?

Comment: to be honest, I cant find it.. edit the picture on paint and add a red circle around the worm.

Comment: And please use the add image button. Do not use third party sites. This one actually is blocked in my lab for some reason (Not your fault actually. My sysadmin needs to be boiled in hot oil. Nonetheless it is better to use the approved image uploader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like an [inchworms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometer_moth) which are the larvae of geometer moth or Geometridae.

By your picture it is almost impossible to see of which type it is.

I took picture of one in Switzerland (but likely not the same as yours).

[image: caterpillar-geometer]

Full resolution here: https://flic.kr/p/utFsiU

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

[image: wireworm]

It's pretty hard to tell from this photo, and I'm no entemologist, but to me, it looks like it may be a **wireworm**, a larvae of a [**click beetle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_beetle). This is a diverse group, so I think it would be pretty difficult to give a specific identification. ([More images](https://www.google.com/search?q=Wireworms&tbm=isch))

Comment: It was attached to the edge of the leaf. It's not on a leaf.